Error in trying preview transactable offers for Microsoft Teams applications
I've created a transactable offer for a Microsoft Team SaaS application.
During the creation you can try to test the offer when it's in a preview state, following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/prepare/test-preview-for-monetized-apps
Following the guide, I receive the following error:
image
I've expected not to have the error shown above

did you definitely make all the "preview" settings, per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/prepare/test-preview-for-monetized-apps#configure-your-app-with-the-preview-offer-id

yes, I did exactly what is written in the guide
